# What does switch do if there is no default case?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have found a following piece of code:

```
switch(val){
    case 0:
        // some actions
       break;
    case 1:
        // some actions
       break;
    case 2:
        // some actions
       break;
}
```

But it is not clear enough what will happen in the case of e.g `val = 10`?

I tried to test this code in a short program with incorrect value, and nothing had happen - program exited normally.

Can this code cause any potential error? Is there any guarantee that nothing will happen?

Comment: A switch is essentially a glorified list of `goto`s, if you think of it that way it's clear that you'll never get an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will simply do nothing and not enter in any case.

It is recommended to have a `default` clause as the final clause in a `switch` statement. Programs like `Lint` will warn if you forget the `default` clause. And for information note that the `default` clause is required in `MISRA-C`.

**EDIT:**

I personally prefer it to be the final clause but I think the most important is for the final clause to be present. Why I prefer it to be the final clause is because of the *Principle of least astonishment*: people are used to see it as the final clause so I think it eases the program reading.

And just for information as I mentioned `Lint` and `MISRA-C` in my answer: `PC-Lint / flexelint` will not warn if `default` is present but not as the final clause and `MISRA-C` explicitly requires `default` to be present as the final clause.

Comment: I sometimes (I'd say very often) put the `default` as the first case label :)

Comment: I prefer not to use `default` clauses with no code.  Tools like Lint complain if you don't have one, but if you are switching on an enum and you add a new possible value to the enum but not your switch statement, having a `default` case prevents the Java compiler from giving you the (far more useful) warning that your switch may be incomplete (ie: you haven't handled the new enum value.)

Answer (score 1):

That is why you should have a default case. It will handle cases other than those you typed.

What Happens in your case is that, it checks the case 0 and it doesn't match and checks case 1 and it also doesn't match and checks the case 2 and it again doesn't match. so it exits..

So it should be this way:

```
switch(val){
    case 0:
        // some actions
       break;
    case 1:
        // some actions
       break;
    case 2:
        // some actions
       break;
    default:
       //some actions
       break;
}
```

Another small point to note: it should case 0: not case 0;

Comment: I supposed that it works like a jump table, not as a sequence of `if-else`

Comment: yes jump table. jumps to the correct value, if it doesn't there should be a default case, so it will hit at least one of them..

Answer (score 1):

If you use any other value from `0, 1, 2` (in this example) nothing will happen. 
`val` will be compared with all values that are in cases and if it will not be equal to one of them, it just will jump to the next statement.